# Resizing images with batch script using ImageMagick

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

I'm trying to write a batch file to resize all the images in a directory to 640 Pixel wide, placing the resized images into a sub-directory called "web-img" and the original pictures should be unchanged.

This was the code I wrote, but it is not working.

```
rem shu chetluru
@echo off    
if not exist "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\proj.uti.1\websize\web-img\nul" md "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\proj.uti.1\websize\web-img"    
mogrify -path "C:\Desktop\proj\websize*.jpg"  -resize 640@ "C:\Desktop\proj\websize\web-img"
```

Can someone please help me to complete and make the code work?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This is so close to a good question. What do you mean "it doesn't work?" Does the script terminate with no output? Does it work but the files are the wrong size? Does your computer blue screen?

Comment: The `-path` option is only meant to take a directory.  Adding a filename with a wild-card (`websize*.jpg`) at the end of the `-path` option is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only info you gave us was *"it is not working"*, I'm only guessing at your intent:

```
mogrify -path "C:\Desktop\proj\"  -resize 640@ *.jpg
```

**Notes:**

- This will resize ALL jpg images in the current directory.
- The new size will be a total of 640 pixels (width x height).  That seems CRAZY small (smaller than a 32x32 icon!  Are you sure that is what you want?)
- The files will be placed in `C:\Desktop\proj\`, but you went through the effort of making directory `C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\proj.uti.1\websize\web-img` Why aren't you using that directory??

You should add a lot more detail to your question.

Comment: OP wants images resized to 640 pixels wide, so you want `-resize 640x`.